# Как исправить ошибку 500 при отправке запроса через Ajax?

Tags: ajax, laravel

Есть форма #reception_data. В форме указан {{ csrf_field() }}. Эту форму сериализую и потравляю примерно так:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/send',
  data: $('#reception_data').serialize(),
  success: function (data) {
    console.log('seccess');
  },
  error: function () {
    console.log('error');
  }
})
```

А в ответ получаю:`500 (Internal Server Error)`

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка 500 (Internal Server Error) это не клиентская часть. Это ошибка на сервере. Продебажте на сервере ваш запрос. Скорее всего у Вас необработанное исключение.

Comment: Ага. по смотрел и понял, что в роут прописано:
Route::post('/send', 'Ajax\SendController@send');
а в контроллере send не было.